# How to allow only 1 radio button selected if they have different names

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I make a script that will not allow for the user to choose various radio buttons? This is my Code:

```
<div class="controls"   >
    <label class="radio"> <input type="radio" <?php echo ($this->state->get('filter.totalinmuebles') == '1') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> name="totalinmuebles" id="totalinmuebles" value="1"> Volumen de inmuebles en venta</label>
    <label class="radio"> <input type="radio" <?php echo ($this->state->get('filter.totalventas') == '1') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> name="totalventas" id="totalventas" value="1"> Total de ventas</label>
    <label class="radio"> <input type="radio" <?php echo ($this->state->get('filter.totalventascliente') == '1') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> name="totalventascliente" id="totalventascliente" value="1"> Total de ventas por cliente</label>
    <label class="radio"> <input type="radio" <?php echo ($this->state->get('filter.totalcomisionescobrar') == '1') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> name="totalcomisionescobrar" id="totalcomisionescobrar" value="1"> Total comisiones a cobrar</label>
</div>
```

I have tried various scripts of my own and from others that I have found on the internet but it doesnt seem to work. The validation should be done without having to click on the "submit" button.

Comment: they all have the same `value`

Comment: Can you detail what you mean by _"will not allow for the user to choose various radio buttons"_

Comment: The radio buttons have different names so they are "considered" as different radio buttons each and you are allow to select all of them if you wish. I dont want that to happen.

Comment: If you want the user to pick one of those four, just give them all the same name but different values. That is how Radio buttons work.

Comment: I cannt allow that. As I said I need a script to do the job. They all have the same value for a reason and different names for a reason too.

Comment: Well with jquery, watch the buttons using `onChange` Event. When one of them is selected, deselect all others using something like their names as a selector. Too obvious? ;-D

Comment: Why do you give me negative reputation without adding comments on what I did wrong? Its always good to know so I can improve future questions. Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to lack basic understanding of HTML usage.

Comment: "I cannt allow that. As I said I need a script to do the job." Why can't you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If adding the same `name` attributes is not an option:

```
$('.controls input').on('change', function() {
   $(this).parent().siblings().find('input').prop('checked', false);
});
```

You can also use the `closest` method:

```
$(this).closest('.controls')
       .find('input[type=radio]')
       .not(this)
       .prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: I have tried your code but doesnt seem to be working :(

Comment: @MONZTAAA You are welcome, it works for me, probably you are missing the document ready handler, http://jsfiddle.net/K2jTp/

Comment: You were correct, forgot to add the document ready handler :) Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job for you:

```
$('#totalinmuebles, #totalventas, #totalventascliente, #totalcomisionescobrar').click(function(){

    var ar=['#totalinmuebles', '#totalventas', '#totalventascliente', '#totalcomisionescobrar'];
    $.each(ar, function( index, value ) {

       $(value).attr('checked',false);
    });

    $(this).attr('checked',true);

});
```

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kGhKC/